# How to reattach all the item that are detached from ttk.treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttkthemes

I am trying to build a search in ttk.treeview. Once I enter the keyword, all unrelated items are detached. However, when I try to restore the treeview, I have to specify each path and reattach every single item. Is there a better way to do so?

I am thinking about duplicate a treeview at first, and restore from that before every search.

Here is my code. (fileListTemp is a dict: {filename:oid})

```
def SearchName(*event):
    keyword = self.entry_1.get()
    for item in self.fileListTemp:
        if keyword.lower() not in item.lower():
            self.treeview.detach(self.fileListTemp[item])
```

Comment: What have you tried on restoring those detached items?

Comment: I may creat a dict for each item and its path and reattach them. It is not wise haha.